# the entity manager is recreating the tables

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

My problem is with the entity manager every time i excute my application it drops tables and the creates them.
I want to retrive data from the data base so how to prevent it from creating new tables? thanks

Comment: What are you using to back JPA?  Hibernate?

Comment: i'm using JPA in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

For hibernate, set your `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` propery in `persistence.xml` to validate.

For eclipselink, use the `eclipselink.ddl-generation` property to `NONE`.

This will prevent the EntityManager from dropping the schema with every execution.